# AVR TWI Status Codes Complete List

Tags: avr, i2c, twi

Can anyone provide a link for complete list of status codes for AVR TWI?

I am working with DS1307 using TWI, during which at some point I receive a status code of 0x40. However there is no mention of this code in the ATmega8 datasheet.

Comment: Check any AVR MCU datasheet. There are status codes for "Master Transmitter Mode" & "Master Receiver Mode"

Comment: @hassansin. Got it. Don't know what I was thinking. Thanks for pointing it out ! Please put it as an answer so I can select it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by user **hassansin**, the remaining codes are under the "Master Receiver" section of TWI.